# Can't use mv command with enough permissions using PHP

Tags: php, linux, shell, exec

I am organizing my folders, the thing is I can't move my files due to permissions but when I checked, folder being created, files being moved and upper level folder is associated with same user and group `apache:apache`. I am also running this php code with `apache` user. What could be the problem?

Quick view;

```
exec('mv '.$path.$result->token.'-*.mp4 '.$path.getWeekNo($result->date).'/ 2>&1', $moveOut, $moveResult);
```

Code:

```
function processFilesByID($db, $path, $id, $type ='token')
{
    $result = $db->get_row('SELECT id,token,title,date FROM DB_TABLE where id="' . $id . '";');
    /* Debug - Start */
     $db->debug();
    // return "ID: " . $result->id . "<br />Token: " . $result->token . "<br />Title: " . $result->title . "<br />Date: " . $result->date;
    /* Debug - End   */
    if (isset($result)) {
        // Check if any file exists with given token command.
        exec('ls -1 ' . $path . $result->token . '-* | wc -l', $out, $res);

        // Check if noOfFile is greater than 0 and less than 10. Also check if command succeed.
        if ($res == 0 && $out[0] > 0 && $out[0] < 10) {
            // Move its media files [WHERE PROBLEM OCCURS]
            exec('mv '.$path.$result->token.'-*.mp4 '.$path.getWeekNo($result->date).'/ 2>&1', $moveOut, $moveResult);
            if($moveResult == 0){
                // Double check if it's moved succesfully.
                exec('ls -1 ' . $path.getWeekNo($result->date).'/'. $result->token . '-* | wc -l', $newOut, $newRes);
                if ($newRes == 0 && $newOut[0] > 0 && $newOut[0] < 10) {
                    // Update DB with new path
                    if($db->query("UPDATE DB_TABLE SET token = '".getWeekNo($result->date).'/'.$result->token."' WHERE id= '".$result->id."'")){
                    }else{
                    }...
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => mv: cannot move '/###PATH###/+++FILE-NAME1+++' to '/###PATH###/16401c4a73848b7be4720d2e13a50a430c7b/+++FILE-NAME1+++': Permission denied
    [1] => mv: cannot move '/###PATH###/+++FILE-NAME2+++' to '/###PATH###/16401c4a73848b7be4720d2e13a50a430c7b/+++FILE-NAME2+++': Permission denied
    [2] => mv: cannot move '/###PATH###/+++FILE-NAME3+++' to '/###PATH###/16401c4a73848b7be4720d2e13a50a430c7b/+++FILE-NAME3+++': Permission denied
)
```

I also tried with php's built-in command but no luck so far.

Comment: Is there a reason why you are moving the files via commands instead of using PHP?

Comment: @Rimble Not really, I tried both, switched to this to make sure what is the error output was

Comment: maybe it's problems with sudoers permissions.

Comment: @miglio The fun thing is I when I do these operations under different document with exact same owner and permissions, it works. :(